# how to make a menu active if the sub menu is a part of main menu

Tags: html, css, menuitem

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="index.html">
      Home
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="pages/gallery.html">
      Gallery
    </a>

  </li>
  <li cl>

    <a href="#service">
      Services
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#brnch">
      Branches
    </a>
  </li>
```

In the index page only I have the service part and branches part. while selecting it from the menu I am getting only the home as an active/selected..

I want when clicked on branches or services that menu item should be selected

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but first we remove the class `.active` from all items, then we assign this class to the clicked item only: [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/vfenwu2y/)

```js
var $items = $('.navbar-nav li');
$items.on('click', function() {
  $items.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  padding 5px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"> <a href="index.html">
      Home
    </a>

  </li>
  <li> <a href="pages/gallery.html">
      Gallery
    </a>

  </li>
  <li cl> <a href="#service">
      Services
    </a>

  </li>
  <li> <a href="#brnch">
      Branches
    </a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using BootStrap just add `class="dropdown active"` to the parent menu